# How to prove commutative from Peano axioms WITHOUT proving associativity first?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

I am reading this [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#:~:text=The%20Peano%20axioms%20define%20the,0%20is%20a%20natural%20number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#:%7E:text=The%20Peano%20axioms%20define%20the,0%20is%20a%20natural%20number).

They use `S(x)` for successor of `x`. Here, I just use `x*` to make it easier to see.

Proofing that commutative works for 0 is easy. 0+0=0

Say successor of `x` is `x*`

Proofing that commutative works if one of the thing we added is 1 is easy

```
x+1=x+0*=(x+0)*=x*
```

Is it the same with `1+x`, well just use induction

Wanna show that `1+x*=1+x**`

`1+0=1`, by peano axiom
now assume `1+x=x*` too
Then `1+x*=(1+x)*=x**` bingo....

Now, we want to proof that `y+x=x+y` for all x and y in natural number

We know it's true that y+x=x+y when both are 0. We know that it's true when one of them is either 0 or 1.

Now we want to show that

```
y*+x=x+y*
```

Then `y*+x=`?

Then what?

How do I show that `y*+x = x+y*`?

I suppose I can do `x+y*=(x+y)*=(y+x)*=y+x*`

Then what?

Should I show that `x+y*=x*+y` first? That is the star can move around in addition? How?

Curiously I can derive associativity first. And then use commutative when one of the things added is 1. But say I don't want something more elegant

What would be the solution?

Sample of similar questions
[Prove the commutativity property of addition of natural numbers by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785576/prove-the-commutativity-property-of-addition-of-natural-numbers-by-induction?noredirect=1&lq=1) This doesn't work. It uses associativity and +1

I basically want to use only star and bracket operation. Successor and bracket.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4516156/peano-addition-commutativity-proof-by-induction) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168914/peano-axioms-and-commutativity-of-addition). Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785576/prove-the-commutativity-property-of-addition-of-natural-numbers-by-induction).

Comment: I changed the question. WITHOUT proofing associativity.

Comment: "It uses associativity and +1" But "+1" IS *successor*.

Comment: Oh it does answer a⊕S(k)=S(a⊕k)=S(k⊕a)=k⊕S(a)=k⊕S(a⊕0)=k⊕(a⊕S(0))=k⊕(S(0)⊕a)=(k⊕S(0))⊕a=S(k⊕0)⊕a=S(k)⊕a

LOL.

So what should I do? Close this one? Nope that one doesn't use associativity.

Comment: Oh wait a minute it has to use associativity. So we need associativity before we proof commutativity? Is that the answer?

Comment: According to this, no you cannot proof commutativity WITHOUT associative. Should I turn this into an answer? https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-the-commutativity-of-addition-from-Peanos-axioms-without-first-proving-the-associativity-of-addition

Comment: Give it a try. If you can proof commutativity without associativity then that would be a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is by Induction, using the property $P(m)=(n+m=m+n)$.

For the base case, we need the Axiom for [sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Peano_arithmetic_as_first-order_theory): $n+0=0$ and we have to prove a preliminary result: $n=0+n$.

[This, in turn, needs induction: base is $0+0=0$ and then, assuming $n=0+n$ we have $s(n)=s(0+n)=0+s(n)$, using axiom.]

Having $n+0=n$ and having proved $n=0+n$, using transitivity of $=$, we get: $n+0=0+n$.

The induction step is: if $n+m=m+n$, then $n+s(m)=s(m)+n$.

Also here we need some preliminary steps involving *successor*: $s(m)+n=s(m+n)$.

[We need induction againz. Base case is: $m+0=m$ by axiom, and thus $s(m+0)=s(m)$. But $s(m)+0=s(m)$ by axiom again, and thus by equality: $s(m)+0=s(m+0)$. The next step assumes $s(m)+n=s(m+n)$ and proves: $s(m)+s(n)=s(m+s(n))$. Using the hypotheses we have: $s(s(m)+n)=s(s(m+n))$ and then $s(s(m+n))=s(m+s(n))$ by axiom; but $s(m)+s(n)=s(s(m)+n)$ by axiom, and using the hypotheses: $s(m)+s(n)=s(s(m+n))$. Thus, by equality: $s(m)+s(n)=s(m+s(n))$.]

We have: $s(m)+n=s(m+n)$ and axiom: $n+s(m)=s(n+m)$; by induction hypothesis: $n+m=m+n$, we get $s(n+m)=s(m+n)$, and thus, by equality:

> $n+s(m)=s(m)+n.$

Now we have proved $P(0)$ and $\forall m [P(m) \to P(s(m))]$ and we can conclude with $\forall m P(m)$, that is:

> $\forall m (n+m=m+n)$.

By generalization: $\forall n \forall m (n+m=m+n)$.

Comment: How do you get this? s(m)+n=s(m+n) actually the peano axioms only define a+s(b) but never s(a)+b. The successor is defined on the right.

Comment: That's where I am stuck actually. If I can show that a+s(b)=s(a)+b=s(a+b) I am golden.

Comment: Obviously with associativity I can do (a+1)+b=a+(1+b). Proofing that 1+b=b+1=s(b) for all b is also not that hard. From that I can proof 2+b=s(s(b))=b+2 and continuing that I seem to be able to proof commutativity. But when I try to put actual letters things fall apart and I am confused.

Comment: This part I understand n+s(m)=s(n+m). That's just definition of addition. s(m)+n=s(m+n)? s(m+n)=s(n+m)=n+s(m) the s is in the right. Not in the left. We want s(n+m)=s(m)+n

How do we get that?

Comment: @user4951: Let me spell it out for you. The induction predicate is $\forall x. s(x) + y = s(x + y)$. **Base case**: $\forall x. s(x) + 0 = s(x + 0)$. Since $\forall z. z + 0 = z$ is an axiom, this is immediate. **Inductive case**: assume $\forall x. s(x) + y = s(x + y)$. The goal is to show $\forall x. s(x) + s(y) = s(x + s(y))$. But you have $s(x) + s(y) = s(s(x) + y)$ by an axiom, $s(s(x) + y) = s(s(x+y))$ by the induction hypothesis, and $s(x+y) = x + s(y)$, so $s(s(x+y)) = s(x + s(y))$. Putting them together, $s(x) + s(y) = s(s(x) + y) = s(s(x+y)) = s(x + s(y))$, which was to be shown.

Comment: Can you add this to the answer. Okay I am checking. Interesting.

Comment: Looks correct. Bingo.. Okay I will study this.

So yea we need double s. That's the catch

Comment: ∀x.s(x)+y=s(x+y) So this is like a lemma isn't it? Great

Comment: @user4951 - correct. Sum is defined with 0 and successor "to the right". We have to show that using them "to the left" gives the same result. And this is commutativety.

Comment: Once I got that lemma I can proof commutativity easily. Very interesting. Wow. Most people proof associativity first. Selected as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to this

Proving commutativity without associativity is either very difficult or impossible. You will still need some special case associativity.

Should I turn this into an answer? https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-the-commutativity-of-addition-from-Peanos-axioms-without-first-proving-the-associativity-of-addition

With associativity I can prove that easily.

So it seems that associativity needs to be proven first and then commutativity.

Update:

@Mauro proof me wrong